# how to build a job from different branches in git?

Tags: git, jenkins

I need to build a job in GIT that depends on other 2 jobs of different repos.

Main job needs to be run only when other 2 jobs already run earlier from different repo's and branches.

So, here's the scenario :

Repo A to be build from one repo X, branch master

Repo B to be build from second repo Y branch master

Then once these 2 jobs ran successfully, then need to run job 3 
Repo C to eb build from repo Z

Can anyone please guide me how to configure this in Jenkins for GIT ?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484512/jenkins-with-multiple-projects-and-git-branches/14491252